# how to retrieve all integers from parts of a string?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

What is the most effective and efficient way to retrieve integers from a string?
For example, my input string is "1s 2ss 5rt" and I only want "1 2 5"
I am using C# and .NET framework

Comment: What has your research into this turned up?

Comment: `\d+`? Is that sample a good representation of the strings you're dealing with? Always post the code you're writing (and doesn't work) along with good samples, when samples are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in 1 google search "c# regex get digits from string"  https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split-numbers

This is the most effective way:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string input = "There are 4 numbers in this string: 40, 30, and 10.";
        // Split on one or more non-digit characters.
        string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
        foreach (string value in numbers)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                int i = int.Parse(value);
                Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

Number: 4
Number: 40
Number: 30
Number: 10

---

RegEx's are quite expensive so the most efficient way is a for loop and IsDigit (but there's a couple of Thai characters that sneak through the IsDigit check).

```
String s = "1s 2ss 5rt";
List<int> digitsInString = new List<int>();
foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c)) digitsInString.Add(Convert.ToInt32(c));
}
```

Comment: Solution in Linq, `List<int> digitsInString = s.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToList();`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar nice one, only thing is LINQ is a tiny bit slower than a for loop and it still has the issue with the Thai characters in the IsDigit check.